# Parseval's theorem

Tags: laplace-transform

In operational calculus there is Parseval's theorem, which states that if $ f(t) \doteqdot F(p), \varphi(t) \doteqdot \Phi(p) $ and both $ F(p) $ and $ \Phi(p) $ are analytical in $ Re p \geq 0 $, then $ \int_0^{+\infty} f(t) \Phi(t) dt = \int_0^{+\infty} \varphi(t) F(t) dt $ (and convergence of one of these integrals implies convergence of the other).

But if one of both functions $ F(p) $ and $ \Phi(p) $ are analytical only in $ Re p > 0 $, then one of the above integrals may converge while the other diverges.
I'm interested in the following question: if these integrals converge, does it guarantees their equality? I can't find the answer in textbooks. Where can i read about this?

Comment: What is the notation of the equality with a dot above and a dot below? (I don't even know its LaTeX name...) Are you saying that one is the Laplace transform of the other?

Comment: $ f(t) \doteqdot F(p) $ means that $ F(p) $ is Laplace transform of $ f(t) $, that is $ F(p) = \int_0^{+\infty} f(t) e^{-p t} dt. $